# What is the tense of "we are needing"

Tags: grammar, tenses

What rule does this violate?  I know that it's wrong, but what is this tense or of what tense is it not a proper form? I hear these a lot: *we are needing* or *we are wanting* instead of *we need* or *we want*.

Comment: The word *are* is in the present tense.

Comment: Now, she had a dream about the king of Sweden,
He gave her things that she was needin',

Answer (score 0):

It's the [present continuous](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/present-continuous-tense/), also known as [present progressive](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/present-progressive).
It's grammatically OK, even though it's not always the most concise expression of an idea.
It indicates the speaker thinks the action is incomplete and wants to emphasize that the main action is ongoing.